# Check if dictionary key is numeric

Tags: vba, dictionary, isnumeric

I have code from a project that looks at options and prices of used cars. It contains a Dictionary of Dictionaries called "DictOfDictMakeModel".

Several "For Each" loops use "IsNumeric" to look for numeric keys in "DictOfDictMakeModel" Keys collection. Finding one, the key is used in reading options from the same Dictionary. This worked until a few days ago.

Debugging I found some keys "IsNumeric" returned as TRUE were strings, but my Dictionary was expecting LONGs.

I fixed the problem but was wondering if there is a better way?

```vb
'Function returns letter IDs of options that are packages, I.E. "Premium Package w/power seats"
Function MSTRpakLtrsCOMRTN() As String
'Return letters of selected Master Package Options
    Dim vKey As Variant
    Dim xKey As Long            'Implicit cast to LONG

'GOOD CODE
    For Each vKey In DictOfDictMakeModel(carModel).Keys
        On Error Resume Next
        xKey = vKey
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            With DictOfDictMakeModel(carModel)(xKey)
                If .NumOrdered > 0 And .MasterPACKname <> "" Then
                    MSTRpakLtrsCOMRTN = MSTRpakLtrsCOMRTN & .MasterPACKname
                End If
            End With
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next vKey

'BAD CODE
'    For Each vKey In DictOfDictMakeModel(carModel).Keys
'        If IsNumeric(vKey) Then             'Skip non-numeric keys
'            With DictOfDictMakeModel(carModel)(vKey)
'                If .NumOrdered > 0 And .MasterPACKname <> "" Then
'                    MSTRpakLtrsCOMRTN = MSTRpakLtrsCOMRTN & .MasterPACKname
'                End If
'            End With
'        End If
'    Next vKey
End Function
```

Comment: [`VarType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) perhaps.

Comment: Would'nt  VarType("4") return  vbString  while

Comment: Oh, I assumed the keys were actually a mix of `Long`s and `String`s, not all `String`s. You could try to `CLng` them and catch the error.

Comment: Wouldn't VarType("4") returns  vbString?  I think xKey = "4" would implicitly convert it to 4 (a Long) which I could use immediately in the following code.

Comment: The keys shouldn't be a mix, but somehow some were being cast to String.  I'll have to look deeper into that.

Comment: Assuming the offending line was `With DictOfDictMakeModel(carModel)(xKey)` why not trap _that_ error, and recover 'only' from it, instead of testing each and every single key, so that performance is _only_ affected by actual error recovery, rather than the testing of _all_ keys?

Comment: You mean wrap it like this?                      On Error Resume Next                                                                                                     
     With DictOfDictMakeModel(carModel)(Clng(xKey)) <more code>                               
    End With                                                                                                                           On Error Goto 0

Comment: I meant `On Error Goto ErrHandle`, where `ErrHandle` would be immediately before the `Next vKey` line so that that iteration would be skipped, assuming that's what should happen

Comment: `With DictOfDictMakeModel(carModel)(CLng(vKey))` ?

Comment: A key of "666" will pass the `IsNumeric()` test, but if there's a corresponding numeric key of 666 then you cannot access that key's value with the string "666" - you first need to turn that "666" into 666.   Plus there's no need for error trapping - you can use `Exists(key)` to check a key exits before trying to access it.

Comment: Tim, "With DictOfDictMakeModel(carModel)(CLng(vKey))" is just a With/EndWith statement to make the following code shorter.  "DictOfDictMakeModel" is a dictionary containing other dictionaries.  "carModel" is a variable used as Key to a dictionary in DictOfDict.  And "CLng(vKey)" is the Key to the objects contained in the "carModel" dictionary.  Hope that helps :-)